# class_existst returns false WP plugin development

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, psr-4

I am following a Wordpress plugin development course, I am blocked now because the method `class_exsists()` of PHP cannot find my class even if everything seems ok, what am I missing?

- I am using **PSR-4** with composer.
- In the tutorial video everything works, I checked folders structure and files diffs, everything matches.

**CODE**

```
defined('ABSPATH') or die('(ಠ_ಠ)┌∩┐ NOPE!');

if (file_exists(__FILE__ . '/vendor/autoload.php')) {
  require_once(dirname(__FILE__) . '/vendor/autoload.php');
}

define('PLUGIN_PATH', plugin_dir_path(__FILE__));

if(class_exists('Inc\\Init')){
  Inc\Init::register_services();
}
```

**FOLDERS STRUCTURE**

[image: This is the structure]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### The problem

The problem is that your autoload file never gets included.

This if-statement:

```
if (file_exists(__FILE__ . '/vendor/autoload.php')) {
```

will never evaluate as true since `__FILE__` returns a string containing the full path *and* the file name of the current file. So your check is basically:

```
if (file_exists('/path/to/file.php/vendor/autoload.php')) {
```

which you can see looks wrong (since it has the `file.php` part as well).

#### Solution

You just want to get the folder name, so lets use `__DIR__` instead:

```
if (file_exists(__DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php')) {
    require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
}
```

You can read more about [PHP's magic constants here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php)

Comment: Thank you very much Magnus, very appreciated. :)

Comment: d= (◕‿↼ ) for fast answer